# How do you execute compass through grunt watch while running an express server?

Tags: express, gruntjs, yeoman, compass-sass, livereload

When I run 'grunt server', everything executes including the compiling of my Sass. How should I proceed to watch for Sass changes and execute compass while keeping the functionality of express and livereload server?

Everything works including livereload when I change files, the only thing that doesn't is the execution of compass to recompile if I change Sass files. It even detects the change, but doesn't run it.

I've attached related pieces of the gruntfile just to keep it as short as possible.

```
'use strict';
var LIVERELOAD_PORT = 35729;
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  var yeomanConfig = {
    app: 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  try {
    yeomanConfig.app = require('./bower.json').appPath || yeomanConfig.app;
  } catch (e) {}

  grunt.initConfig({
    yeoman: yeomanConfig,
    watch: {
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      compass: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: LIVERELOAD_PORT
        },
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },
    express: {
      options: {
        port: 3000,
        hostname: '*'
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: true,
          serverreload: false,
          server: path.resolve('app.js'),
          bases: [path.resolve('./.tmp'), path.resolve(__dirname, yeomanConfig.app)],
          files: [
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
            '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            // '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png,svg,webp}'
          ]
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          server: path.resolve('app.js'),
          bases: [path.resolve('./.tmp'), path.resolve(__dirname, 'test')]
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          server: path.resolve('app.js'),
          bases: path.resolve(__dirname, yeomanConfig.dist)
        }
      }
    },
    open: {
      server: {
        url: 'http://localhost:<%= express.options.port %>'
      }
    },

    compass: {
      options: {
        sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        cssDir: '.tmp/styles'
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
        }
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          debugInfo: true
        }
      }
    },

    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'compass:server',
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      test: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      dist: [
        'compass',
        'copy:styles',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'open', 'express:dist', 'express-keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'express:livereload',
      'open',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concurrent:test',
    'express:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'copy:dist',
    'modernizr',
    'rev',
    'usemin',
    'cdnify',
    'ngmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'compass',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are you using grunt-contrib-compass, I suggest you use native compass watcher. It works much faster than rebuilding with grunt. If you enable it, you have to run it via grunt-concurrent, more informations [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass#watch).